# Carousel image view - inlineBlock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'D like to create a carousel using some html like this combined with `slick.js`:

```css
.view {
    position: relative;
    width: 47%;
    margin: 1%;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  .view.active {
    opacity: 1
  }
  .container_view {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    top: 10%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px solid orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container_view">
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="view active" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Swiping left or right should every time display the next **slide**. So I tried to implement slick.js but obviously this was not the right way to do because the image view now looks pretty destroyed:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container_view").slick({
    dots: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    infinite: false,
    /*variableWidth: true*/
  })
})
```

```css
.view {
  position: relative;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.view.active {
  opacity: 1
}

.container_view {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 10%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border: 6px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css">


<div class="container_view">
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="view active" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view active" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this **carousel** to make the slides look like the image view from the first snippet? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use either grid or flex for your layout https://gridbyexample.com/examples/ https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, but the issue is that the `.slick-slide img` class has a `display: block` property attached, which overwrites the `display: inline-block` on the `.view` css class.

A quickfix is to add to add the !important tag to the .view class

```
.view {
  position: relative;
  width: 47%;
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

This will ensure the display property to overwrite the display block coming from .slick-slide img

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonaspraem/xpvt214o/919869/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please note that I just want to display **One** slide (4 images - two in each of the two rows) at the same time - the next slide should have enough space between the first that it does not get displayed.

Comment: oh, somehow i understood the opposite - will work on a edited answer

Comment: You can easily move out the next element by doing `.slick-list {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 50px !important; 
}` - But the way that slick styles everything makes it really annoying to work with imo

Answer (score 1):

Simply add !important to your css . which is not applied before. or you can use swiper slider/Owl carousel which gives you more option to show slide per screen and also as per screen resoultion.

Check these sliders plugin with hardware accelerated transitions and amazing native behaviour-

1- https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

2- https://idangero.us/swiper/

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container_view").slick({
    dots: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    infinite: false,
    /*variableWidth: true*/
  })
})
```

```css
.view {
  position: relative;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1%;
  /*Simply Add important to display */
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.view.active {
  opacity: 1
}

.container_view {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 10%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  border: 6px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css">


<div class="container_view">
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="view active" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view active" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
    <img class="view" src="https://i1.wp.com/androidkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Stack_Overflow.png?fit=700%2C394&ssl=1">
  </div>
</div>
```